# Why does Superman fly headfirst?

Tags: dc, superman

Like almost all superheroes who can fly, Superman almost always flies headfirst, often with his fist extended in front of him.

There doesn't seem to be any reason why this pose would be superior to any other, unless he's in a serious rush to get somewhere.  Why not fly feet first, or sideways, or standing up, or sitting Indian style?

When Superman is just getting from one place to another and isn't in a hurry, why does he fly headfirst?

Comment: Because it looks cool?

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24910/why-does-superman-put-one-or-both-arms-up-when-he-flies

Comment: Because if he flew butt-first, he'd look like an idiot as he crashed into things

Comment: *"Unless he's in a serious rush"* - saving lives is a serious matter. Pureblood ones at least.

Comment: He doesn’t fly head-first when he’s coming in for landing…

Comment: Maybe he is trying to be polite by reducing the magnitude of the sonic booms he must be constantly shattering windows, eardrums and roof tiles with... Its not like he flies at very high altitude most of the time. (Except when he flies at *insane* altitude and does stuff in space...) Anyway, it doesn't appear that he cares about efficiency, the guy can clearly get more energy out of his food than you or I (and the idea that his extra inputs are solar is... ?).

Comment: Clearly _someone_'s never studied aerodynamics (streamlining, turbulence, etc.) ;-)

Comment: In "The Call" (an episode of the animated series "Batman Beyond"), we see him flying with an alien mind-control starfish covering his face; he is in a standing position, arms at his side, feet toward the ground while flying horizontally. The effect is quite unnerving.

Comment: @randal'thor - I understand that would be important if he was in a hurry, but not when he's just screwing around.

Comment: @Richard - I used to crack up when I imagined Superman in civilian clothes, pretending he was out of control, flying backwards bent in half, smashing through buildings, and screaming "HELP ME, PLEASE HELP ME!!  WHAT'S HAPPENING TO ME?  AAAAAAAAAAAHHHH!"

Comment: @Richard Whaaat!? Are you saying Powdered Toast Man [looks like an idiot](http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_ltchy8wCph1qk072ho1_500.gif)? Please be more sensitive to superheroes with, ahem, alternate flying postures.

Comment: I thought I'd be all clever and be like "Oh, but the Hindu god Hanuman flies sitting Indian-style"  Then I looked up images of Hanuman flying, and no.  Superman style.  BUT!  Goku in Dragonball, a superhero based on Hanuman, flies standing or sitting on a tiny cloud.  Which probably doesn't really count.

Comment: @WadCheber: like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_58-toZCGt8)?

Comment: Because there's only one Powdered Toast Man and Superman ain't him!!!

Comment: Out-of-universe he originally didn't fly. He leaped and landed feet first. Viewers mistook depictions of him at the start of his leap or mid leap for sustained flight. I think that the intent of the early artists to depict acrobatic leaping explains much of his pose.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From ***[FASTER: Demystifying the Science of Triathlon Speed](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Q52IBwAAQBAJ)*** (2013) by triathlete and aeronautical engineer Jim Gourley:

> **It's why Superman flies head first.** With that huge cape adding so much drag, he needs to be as efficient as possible!  The most common way to reduce your frontal area is to lean farther over the aerobars on the bike or improve your streamline position in the water. Coaches and bike fitters go to great lengths to emphasize this, **because unnecessary frontal area significantly compromises performance.**

In other words, by flying horizontally, friction is significantly reduced.  Flying standing up, for example, presents a lot more surface area for air resistance.

This is consistent with the fact that Superman *doesn't always fly head first*.  When he's not concerned about speed or efficiency, or when he is performing a particular maneuver, he may adopt other positions:

[image]

Comment: But what if he doesn't care how long a flight lasts?  Even when he's just floating around slowly, taking in the scenery, he is headfirst

Comment: @WadCheber : See added info.

Comment: Great answer. Another reason is probably that you have a lot better vison of where you are going flying head first, compared to flying to flying feet first which would also have low air resistance.

Comment: “Even when he's just floating around slowly, taking in the scenery, he is headfirst” Do we see Superman on a lot of recreational flights?

Comment: @SJuan76 In some versions of the story, the cape has a pocket for him to stash his civilian clothes in.

Comment: Wearing a cape is a stylistic choice, like the same reason he doesn't wear a mask or wears an outfit made of bright colours.

Answer (score 13):

My guess is that it is mainly for the same reason that the cockpit is nearly always positioned in the front of an airplane.  The reason for this seems to basically be visibility.

Source: http://www.quora.com/Why-is-the-cockpit-in-the-front-of-the-plane

Visibility is probably not a matter of personal safety for Superman - crashing into something might not kill him - but, being a nice guy, he probably wouldn't want to destroy an airplane filled with people in mid-flight.  Even if he managed to save them all, it would probably ruin their day.  And even when there are no airplanes around, crashing into fifteen geese is likely not that fun either.

My own personal addition to Superman flying headfirst is that it makes more sense anatomically.  His head (or, often, his extended arm) is one item, whereas his legs are two separate items.  Air resistance, enormous at these speeds, will likely work to pry his legs apart and make them flail every which way.  Of course, he is Superman, so he has enough muscle to keep them together, but why get distracted by the unnecessary muscle tension?  Just fly head (arm) first, and leave legs in the back to drag.

[image]

Superman is also occasionally portrayed with both arms extended.  In principle, this makes some sense as well, if the double-arm pose was the water-dynamic pose used by divers.

However, the occasional double-arm pose tends to be closer to this:

[image]

Now this one I find rather impractical.  The only way extending your arms would make sense is if you A. Keep your hands together, B. keep your hands open and not in fists, and C. tuck your head in.  The obvious reason for the less practical pose is that it looks extra cool, but come on Superman.  Everyone already knows you're heroic and whatnot.

[image]
Yes.

[image]
No.

Comment: extending your arms in front of you is to protect your face. okok, he's invincible, but it's still an "early warning systen", and it's a natural pose. it's the same reason a person would walk with their hands stretched out in front of them in the dark. so that something hits your hands before it hits your face or torso. again it's a natural thing to do, it doesn't have to be specifically necessary for superman to do.

Comment: @Sahuagin Seems to me that you would be far safer with your arms not blocking your field of view. Besides, what would they protect you against? Up in the sky you're likely to encounter object like airplanes and eagles - things you would probably see a mile away, even with normal human vision. I suppose you could bump into a falling meteorite or something, but extended fists aren't that likely to protect your face against that. No, that doesn't seem practical at all.

Comment: @MishaRosnach These are basic human instincts—they’re not based on in-the-situation logic. And since Superman comes from a race of perfectly normal humanoids and is only special and invincible here on Earth, it would make sense for him to have the same instincts and reflexes as the rest of us.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That isn't really how instincts work. A basic human instinct might make a person briefly push both arms out the first time they fly, but they would soon learn to stick to a more useful pose. Take a look at the picture of a skydiver in one of the answers here.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Skydivers have a reason for needing to overcome the instinctive hands-first protective position. Superman doesn't really; and if there's no real need to consciously learn to override instinctive movements, they'll probably just stay and become habit. It's not like there's any real disadvantage to it when you're Superman anyway.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well, no reason other than arms blocking his field of view. Using x-ray vision for two large blind spots seems a bit odd when you could just stop sticking your arms out.

Comment: @MishaRosnach Wouldn't he most commonly be looking down on what he's flying over, anyway, apart from when checking for airplanes and geese in the vicinity? Even if not, having your arms stretched out in front of you doesn't really block your field of view enough to be particularly noticeable. If he'd been a regular human being, he'd likely get very tired arms and give it up, but that's hardly an issue with Superman.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet He seems to be looking directly ahead in most illustrations and shots. But my guess is that at least at some point he would look to the left and slightly down. At which point he would notice that there is an arm in the way. I would then think he should move that arm, realize there really isn't a good reason to stick it back out, and leave the arm behind him.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Of course the obvious response is that he doesn't seem to be doing that. I mean there he is, arm extended 9 out of 10 times. So I suppose we have a superhero with a bit of a learning disability, or a superhero with a bit of an inferiority complex who wants to make sure he looks extra awesome. Or he secretly harbors a phobia of flying that he just can't seem to shake. Or maybe his anatomy is a bit different, and this is much easier for him somehow.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as an ex-skydiver, if you want to fly forward relative to the ground, you don't put your arms in front, you hold them backwards. Something like this.

[image]

When diving into water you clasp your hands ahead of you only to protect your head by breaking the surface of the water.

I suggest that because Superman can presumably fly faster than sound, he is being considerate to people on the ground by holding a hand or hands in front, reducing the shockwave he produces. Also this will prevent his hairstyle from being disturbed too much.

Finally I don't believe superman has super clothes (??). Therefore, to avoid them being destroyed by the enormous wind-force, he is deflecting the airflow away from them with his bare fist.

Comment: `I don't believe superman has super clothes` I assume he has or it would have an awful lot of bullet holes in it by now :)

Comment: @JaneS -  Where did he get the super fabric from though? Didn't he catch the bullets in his hands? Presumably he has plenty of spare suits at home. In the first Christopher Reeve movie I think his adopted mother (Martha Kent) made his first suit. (?)

Comment: If I recall canon (I'm far from an expert), his suit was made from the swaddling cloth he was wrapped in as a baby in his space ship.  My comment was based on a scene from Superman Returns where someone is shooting a minigun into his chest and his suit is completely undamaged :)

Comment: There's a fair discussion on his suit here: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13034/does-superman-clean-his-uniform?rq=1

Comment: I wonder how Martha managed to cut the swaddling cloth with Earth scissors.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Haha, guilty :)  Got a phone txt, and forgot to read the rest.  Useless comment removed.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK However... Speaking as someone who used to swim competitively in high school - that position does not *only* serve to protect your head.  It is also to decrease water resistance (well, and to make sure your arms are ready to push water back).  Admittedly, the hand position is slightly different for a competitive swimmer than for a competitive diver, but the arms-in-front head-tucked-in part is the same.  That's why the best competitive divers create the smallest splashes.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK I suspect that Clark was old enough to help and probably used his laser vision to cut the cloth.  How they sewed it though, well... :)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK IIRC in the versions of the story where this happened at all, she unravelled the cloth and rewove it in the new shape. (Other versions of the story have him generate a protective field that extends 1mm or so beyond his skin.)

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: As I recall, in that movie Clark walks into the Fortress of Solitude in jeans and a flannel shirt, then a few years later flies out in the suit, and no further explanation is offered.

Answer (score 2):

Let me quote the titular story from Eric Knight's *The Flying Yorkshireman*, from when Sam Small gains the power of flight and learns to control it.

> For, curiously enough, although all the movements that a bird makes normally in flight came natural to him, he had to learn of his own accord the evolutions that an airplane can achieve.

I would guess Superman is similar: flying headfirst comes to him by instinct.